# Why does the ResizeObserver constructor callback accept an array of entries instead of a single entry?

Tags: javascript, dom

Considering the `ResizeObserver` [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver/ResizeObserver), whose first argument is a callback which accepts two arguments, first of which is an array of `ResizeObserverEntry` objects, what are the differences between those entries (if any)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey You're right thanks!

Comment: Honestly, you really have to go through the [algorithms that go into the Resize Observer API standard](https://drafts.csswg.org/resize-observer/#algorithms). If I tell you that each entry represents an observer target related to active observation, that's not going to tell you much without an explanation of all of those terms...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be explained in simple terms:

- Each time you call `.observe(newElement)` a new entry is added to (the end of) the list in the callback - unless the element is already being observed.
- If you call `.unobserve(newElement)`, the respective entry is removed
  from the list.
- In simple cases, you can use `entries[index]`, if you know the index - for example, there's always going to be just one entry: `entries[0]`.
- While iterating the list of entries `entry.target` gives you the element observed.

Comment: So, if you observe multiple elements, and if one of them changes sizes, the callback function fires with all of the elements as parameters in the entries array? How would you know which element changed sizes?

Comment: To answer the first question: yes, exactly. To answer the second: I think the purpose is to group together such targets that if any of them is changed, it triggers the same effect. Note that it only triggers once, in case multiple were changed. If you want to know which ones were changed, you could make a new resizer observer for each element - or if you have the last values stored, you could check for changes manually and see which were changed.