# What are the elements in the ResizeObserver callback

Tags: javascript, dom

The documentation and the canonical examples of the `ResizeObserver` show that the callback function receives

> An array of ResizeObserverEntry objects that can be used to access the
> new dimensions of the element after each change.

Do I understand this API correctly and typically, it should be enough to just use the last array element to get the "final" size of the element?

```js
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
   const finalElement = entries[entries.length - 1];
   const finalBoxSize = finalElement.contentBoxSize;

   console.log(finalBoxSize);
});
```

Comment: This answer explains it better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69690616/2082521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely that is not the correct way. To me, it looks like it really depends how accurate your "query" for the element to be observed is. Take look at the properties defined in the callback array objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserverEntry). The callback returns an array of those objects. If you have a very specific "query" e.g. element with an id it should return only one element, if you pass just a div, then it will likely return an array of every div on the page as a separate entry. I haven't tried it myself so there is some guessing done here.

Comment: The method `ResizeObserver.observe` only allows an Element as parameter, so how could I receive an array of elements as you suggest?

Comment: Check the bottom of the page I linked. It depends on the query.

Comment: Are you referring to the „ A reference to the Element or SVGElement being observed“ in the documentation? Does this imply that multiple target elements can be observed? How would you specify multiple elements in the „observe“ method?

Comment: My bad, it supports only one element as you said. I got fooled by the entries array. The callback returns one element in an array and to be future proof you probably want to iterate it through as shown in the examples instead of trusting it to be the last one (which it is for now). Notice also Firefox and Chrome difference. Entry of entries is a single item in Firefox and an array in Chrome as shown in the examples.

Comment: [Here is a small messy fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/janza/04rhj5ut/88/)